# Mulitple Fetches in Loop using Counter and Array

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo, fetch

I've been having an issue executing prepared queries using bindParam() with PDO in a loop. Basically what I'm trying to do is loop through an array, and with each array element, return the data from the database. Now I realise that ->bindParam() is supposed to bind the variable to the query, but how does this work with arrays? Because I can't seem to get it working :S

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");
    $statement->bindParam(":id", $friendListIDs[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $friendListIDs = explode($details['friends'], " ");
    while($i <= count($friendListIDs))
    {
          $statement->execute();
          $row = $statement->fetch();
          echo "<img src='../img/friend_icon.png' alt='' align='left' />
                <span>
                <a href='#'>".$row['firstname']." ".$row['surname']."</a>
                <br />
                <a href='#'>100% wishes fulfilled</a>
                </span><br /><br />";
                $i++;
    }   
?>
```

Comment: try `$statement->bindParam(":id", $friendListIDs[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);` inside the while.

Comment: Side note here: You'll get better performance if you get all your results in one select, then iterate through the returned values in php. Less round trips for the same amount of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use `bindParam` you can add an array parameter to `$statement->execute` like so:

```
$statement->execute(array(":id"=>$friendListIDs[$i]));
```